# Having trouble configuring the swiftmailer files downloaded from swiftmailer.org

Tags: php, oop, email

Hello and thanks in advance for anyone who helps me with this problem.

This is 100% a last resort, as I am very stubborn and have a DIY attitude, but have searched as much as possible for an solution to my problem.

I am trying to configure the swiftmailer files downloaded from swiftmailer.org. From what I've gathered there are supposed to be multiple files in the download, but I got just one file in a folder. And it also states that there will be a lib folder, which was not present in the download. And in the scripts I have read of actual swiftmailer email programs, they require a file called swift_required.php which was not present in the downloaded. I attempted to just logically put the script together from what I had, so renamed the one file that was in the download to swift_required.php, and put it in a folder I named lib, but this did not work.

I hope I have given enough information, and would greatly appreciate some help.

Comment: I would like to be enlightened as to why this question is 'off topic'? This is directly about php programming, using the swiftmailer library to send emails with the php programming language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

down load: http://swiftmailer.org/download_file/Swift-5.0.1.tar.gz

then from the command line run:

```
tar -zxvf Swift-5.0.1.tar.gz
```

tar.gz means the file is a tar ball that's then compressed with gzip. It's usually a 2 stage process to extract. first- unzip then, untar, but it can be done in one command as above.

If using windows, i suggest 7zip (http://www.7-zip.org/)

7-zip step by step:

file- open
double click on the file in the z-zip window (currently with a  a *G* on the file icon)
now you should see the file name again *NO G*
highlight it
click extract at the top
select destination
it will create the full directory structure

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. which command line are you referring to? I tried downloading the files previously and extracted them using 7-zip, as the notes on the swiftmailer.org instructed but ended up with just one file. When using the 7-zip am I supposed to just extract files? as thats what I did, but only ended up with the one file, and no lib folder.

Comment: sounds like you extracted the tarball. see the question update.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I have marked your answer as correct!